# How to change multiple URL parameters in angularjs using $location.search()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a URL with three parameters

www.example.com/home?id=123456789&type=all&page=2

On a particular click, I would like to change only **two** parameters out of **three**.
Currently, I'm doing this

```
let params = $location.search();
$location.search({'id': params.id, 'type': 'settled', 'page': 1});
```

Is there a more elegant way that I could be doing this?
Something like `$location.search('page', 1)` but for more than one parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add properties to an object use [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
let params = $location.search();
params.type = "settled";
params.page = 1;

$location.search(params);
```